# How to drag and drop an item on an other item?

Tags: java, minecraft

I would like to create a system for drag and drop my custom enchanted book on for example a sword. Precisely, I make for you an example :

You've an enchanted book, and you should drag and drop him on your diamond sword for set the enchantment to your diamond sword. And, when you did it, the enchanted book is removed, and the name of the enchantment is showed in the lore of your sword.

Have you an idea for make this? Thanks in advance.

I program this on Spigot 1.12.2, and my class is granted.

That's my code now, but he doesn't work (the message don't show) :

```java
    @EventHandler
    public void onClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
        if(e.getWhoClicked() instanceof Player) {
            Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();

            if(e.getAction().equals(InventoryAction.SWAP_WITH_CURSOR)) {
                if(e.getCursor() == null || e.getCurrentItem() == null) return;

                if(!e.getCursor().hasItemMeta()) return;

                ItemMeta cursorM = e.getCursor().getItemMeta();

                if(cursorM.getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("§atest")) {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("test OK");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't have error or other, my logs is clean.

Answer (score 0):

First, `InventoryAction.SWAP_WITH_CURSOR` is just triggered when "The clicked item and the cursor are exchanged[...]". See https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/inventory/InventoryAction.html
So, I would try using the `InventoryAction`s `PLACE_ALL`, `PLACE_ONE` and `PLACE_SOME` or similar.

A tip for debugging: If your debug message is NOT showing, try to place a debug message before your actual debug message, containing the result of the query, used to trigger your debug message. In your case, you could place the debug message `Bukkit.broadcastMessage("InventoryAction: " + e.getAction().toString());` before the query `if(e.getAction().equals(InventoryAction.SWAP_WITH_CURSOR)) {`. And the debug message `Bukkit.broadcastMessage("isCancelled:" + (e.getCursor() == null || e.getCurrentItem() == null));` before the first `return;`, and so on...

So you are able to determine, where your event stucks!